# Where can I find standardized implementations of lightweight cryptographic ciphers?

Tags: elliptic-curves, lightweight, affine-cipher, hill-cipher, present

I am working on a project that requires encrypting messages with different ciphers. I am looking for the following ciphers:

- PRESENT,
- CLEFIA,
- LEA,
- Hill cipher,
- Affine cipher,
- Elliptic Curve Cryptography.

In the past, I used AES from `openssl` UNIX utility which is pretty much standardized. 
I found some implementations on github which may be faulty as there is no associated confidence with them. Since the whole project actually relies on this step, it is desirable that I use the most standardized implementations of these ciphers.

I might also implement them on my own but there is no use reinventing the wheel. I feel there exist standardized ones out there. I searched at NIST website too but to no avail.

Please let me know if you know of some standardized implementations that most of the community uses. Apologies for sounding like a newbie. I am quite new to the interesting world of cryptography.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Present and Clefia are ISO standards . You should google it. You can find present implementation in http://lightweightcrypto.org/present/

Comment: @hardyrama Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I wanted. If someone could guide me to other ciphers' implementation too, that would be great.